# laravel 4 display query user by 1d

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 for a web project , I am creating an admin panel

in the admin I have admin/profile/{id} to display user profile like firstname lastname etc..

in my AdminController I have :

```
     // get the Admin Profile page
    public function getProfile($id) {

    // get the user from the database
    $user = User::find($id);
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.profile', array('user' => $user));

    }
```

but what happens I keep getting errors if I just go to admin/profile without any user id? , how do i make it work?

Basically how to make if the page doesn't exist to go to the dashboard or something like that ? for example if they tried admin/test and test is not a method there , if they are login it will go ot teh dashboard , if not it will go to login page?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two questions:

1. I get a 404 error if I go to `admin/profile` without a user ID. How can I redirect to the login page?
2. How can I redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in.

For the first question, you can do it a couple of ways. One solution is to add a route that matches anything **after all your other route definitions**:

```
Route::get('{any_url}', function(){ return Redirect::route("login"); });
```

This **must** be the last route defined because it will match **any** URL.

Another way to do it would be to catch the `NotFoundHttpException` in your `start/global.php` file. Add this code:

```
App::error(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $exception, $code)
{
    return Redirect::route("login");
});
```

Both of these examples redirect to a named route called `login`.

As for your second question, the correct way to handle this is to use the `auth` filter. In your `filters.php` file, you can add something like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route)
{
    // is the user authorized? if not, redirect to the login page
    if (!user_is_authorized())
    {
            // redirect to the login page
            return Redirect::route('login');
    }
});
```

Where the `user_is_authorized` function is just shorthand for whatever check you do in your code. For information on using the `auth` filter, see http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters.

Comment: for the 1st question if I add the NotFoundHttpException isnt that for my whole application , so whenever there is an error it will be redirected to login page??

Comment: Can I add a code to my getProfile($id) where is the id is not set , redirect to dashboard for example? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, the `NotFoundHttpException` will apply to your whole application. If you don't want that, do something else. For your second comment, yes, that will work too, if you make the `{id}` parameter in your route optional.

Comment: this what I have in my route : Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController'); how to make it optional?

Comment: I have tried this in my AdminController:   
   public function getProfile($id) {
        if(!isset($id)) Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
  
   $user = User::find($id);
   
        $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.profile', array('user' => $user));
 
   }  but still getting error : Missing argument 1 for AdminController::getProfile()

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `missing` handler (handles `404`) like this:

```
App::missing(function($e){
    // Log the missing url
    Log::error($e);

    // You may redirect to home
    return Redirect::to('/');

    // Or redirect to a 404 route that is declared
    // to show a custom 404 page from that route
    return Redirect::to('missing');
});
```

Put the code (given above) in your `app/start/global.php` file. For the `missing` `url/route` you need to crate add a route in your `routes.php` file like this:

```
Route::get('missing', function(){
    // show the view: errors.missing
    $this->layout->content = View::make('errors.missing');
});
```

Create a `view` as `views/errors/missing.blade.php` and in your `missing.blade.php` view, show a fancy message to inform the visitor that, the `requested page/url` is not available and add a link to your home page in that `404` page.

Read more on `Laravel` website about [Errors & Logging](http://laravel.com/docs/errors), check [Handling 404 Errors](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors).